# problems with handeling Json request in play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm trying to make server which can handle HTTP requests with Json. Sorry if I haver. I'm just still new to all this.
So, I made function which takes JsValue and working with it.

```
    def find(info: JsValue) = {
        val req = Search.makeRequest("person",info) 
        val result = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
            SQL(req).as(person *)
        }
        Json.toJson(result)
    }
```

Then I do something like this:

```
val test = Json.parse("""{"name":"John"}""")
Person.find(test)
```

It works fine. But then I try to call this function with HTTP request:

routes file:

```
GET     /findperson                 controllers.PersonController.findPerson(info: String)
```

controller:

```
def findPerson(info: String) = Action {
 Ok(Person.find(Json.parse(info)))
}
```

actual request:

```
http://localhost:9000/findperson?info="""{"name":"John"}"""
```

I get:

```
 Exception: Malformed JSON: Got a sequence of JsValue outside an array or an object.
```

Can someone tell me how do it right? Please.

Comment: You probably don't want to pass JSON in your query string.  If you need to send JSON, use a POST or PUT method and extract it from the body.  You should start by reading Play's documentation on JSON: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson

Comment: Yes, I read it a couple of times, but it looks like I need to read it again. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with @Ryan that it is an unusual thing to want to do, I think the problem you are having is actually as the message says, "Malformed JSON". Remember that your url parameter is not source code, it's a simple string. There's no need to escape the quotation marks. So try using the url:

```
http://localhost:9000/findperson?info={"name":"John"}
```